# Make element blink with color

Tags: jquery

I am using **jQuery 3.4.1**.

I want this element to blink the user with its background color. Not be blinking, but just change background color and then change the color back again.

```
$code_sample.addClass("background-color-light-green").delay(500).removeClass("background-color-light-green");
```

When I trigger the event, no visible effect is present.

https://jsfiddle.net/Nonverbis/nzx7dvm8/2/

What can I try to fix this?

Comment: .removeClass, .addClass are very basic commands, hence do not use queue effects like .hide(), .show(), hence we must use set timeout to handle such problems!

Comment: Thank you. Working. If you organize the answer something like this: 

    function remove_background_color($code_sample){
        $code_sample.removeClass("background-color-light-green");
    }

    function blink_background_color($code_sample){
        $code_sample.addClass("background-color-light-green");
        setTimeout(function(){remove_background_color($code_sample)}, 200);
    }

I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `.removeClass()`, `.addClass()` are very basic commands, hence do not use queue effects like `.hide()`, `.show()`,meaning they can't be chained, Hence we must use set timeout to handle such problems!

```
function remove_background_color($code_sample) { 
    $code_sample.removeClass("background-color-light-green");
}

function blink_background_color($code_sample) {
    $code_sample.addClass("background-color-light-green");
    setTimeout(function(){
        remove_background_color($code_sample)
    } , 200); 
}
blink_background_color($('#code-sample-1'))
```